# Normalization of Year bringing nulls back

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    YEAR(DateRegistered) as Years,
    Months.[MonthName], 
    COUNT(UserID)as totalReg 
FROM 
    Months WITH(NOLOCK)
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    UserProfile WITH(NOLOCK)
ON 
    Months.MonthID = MONTH(DateRegistered)
AND
    DateRegistered > DATEADD(MONTH, -12,GETDATE())

GROUP BY YEAR(DateRegistered), Months.[MonthName]
ORDER BY Months.[MonthName]
```

As you can tell this will always bring back 12 months worth of data.  As such it is working, although there is a bug with this method.

It creates Null values in months where there is no data, now the record should exist(whole point of the query) but Year field is bringing Nulls which is something I dont want.

Now I understand the problem is because there is no data, how is it supposed to know what year?

So my question is - is there any way to sort this out and replace the nulls? I suspect I will have to completely change my methodology.

```
**YEAR**    **MONTH**             **TOTAL**
2013    April                   1
2013    August                  1
NULL    December                0
2013    February                8
2013    January                 1
2013    July                    1
NULL    June                    0
2013    March                   4
NULL    May                     0
NULL    November                0
NULL    October                 0
2012    September               3
```

Comment: Can you post your schema?

Comment: posted the results that i get from my query, there as expected, my problem is how do i replace these nulls since my query doesnt know if it should be october 2012 or 2013

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want 12 months of data, then construct a list of numbers from 1 to 12 and use these as offsets with `getdate()`:

```
with nums as (
      select 12 as level union all
      select level - 1
      from nums
      where level > 1
    )
 select YEAR(thedate) as Years,
        Months.[MonthName], 
        COUNT(UserID) as totalReg 
 FROM (select DATEADD(MONTH, - nums.level, GETDATE()) as thedate
       from nums
      ) mon12 left outer join
      Months WITH (NOLOCK)
      on month(mon12.thedate) = months.monthid left outer join
      UserProfile WITH (NOLOCK)
      ON Months.MonthID = MONTH(DateRegistered) and
         DateRegistered > DATEADD(MONTH, -12, GETDATE())
GROUP BY YEAR(thedate), Months.[MonthName]
ORDER BY Months.[MonthName];
```

I find something strange about the query though.  You are defining the span from the current date.  However, you seem to be splitting the months themselves on calendar boundaries.  I also find the table `months` to be awkward.  Why aren't you just using the `datename()` and `month()` functions?

Comment: Yeh the Table months is terrible, but it was there being used already so i thought why not.  The point of this query was to obtain always 12 records (months) and display a value and a year.
"You are defining the span from the current date. However, you seem to be splitting the months themselves on calendar boundaries."? what do you mean by this, am I doing something that could be done better? could you show me? didn't even realise I was hehe!

Comment: oh btw, mon12.thedate needs to be in the Group by clause could you update please? (excellent answer btw! but I have a feeling there is a better more preffered way of doing this?)

Comment: @StevenSmith . . . If the current date is Aug 15th, then you are going back to the middle of a month for the beginning of a period.  And then presumably only using half of that month for the final report.

Comment: I know !!! i said Exactly the same!!!! but the client said they dont want it like that they want it 12months by date...I tried to explain to them that if you select middle of the month your gona get half the data and it wont make any sense on a graph (query to be used in graph)...

Answer (score 1):

Try this out:

```
;With dates as (
Select  DateName(Month, getdate()) as [Month],
        DatePart(Year, getdate()) as [Year],
        1 as Iteration

Union All

Select  DateName(Month,DATEADD(MONTH, -Iteration, getdate())),
        DatePart(Year,DATEADD(MONTH, -Iteration, getdate())),
        Iteration + 1

from dates
where  Iteration < 12
)
SELECT DISTINCT
        d.Year,
        d.Month as [MonthName], 
        COUNT(up.UserID)as totalReg 
FROM dates d
LEFT OUTER JOIN UserProfile up ON d.Month = DateName(DateRegistered)
                                And d.Year = DatePart(Year, DateRegistered)
GROUP BY d.Year, d.Month
ORDER BY d.Year, d.Month
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to calculate the counts in a Derived Table (or a CTE) first and then join

untested:

```
SELECT 
    COALESCE(dt.Years, YEAR(DATEADD(MONTH, -Months.MonthID, GETDATE()))),
    Months.[MonthName], 
    COALESCE(dt.totalReg, 0) 
FROM 
    Months WITH(NOLOCK)
LEFT OUTER JOIN
 (
   SELECT 
       YEAR(DateRegistered) AS Years,
       MONTH(DateRegistered) AS Mon,
       COUNT(UserID)AS totalReg
   FROM UserProfile WITH(NOLOCK)
   WHERE DateRegistered > DATEADD(MONTH, -12,GETDATE())
   GROUP BY 
       YEAR(DateRegistered),
       MONTH(DateRegistered)
 ) AS dt
ON Months.MonthID = dt.mon
ORDER BY 1, Months.MonthID
```

I changed the order to Months.MonthID instead of MonthName and i added year because you might have august 2012 and 2013 in your result.

Comment: just tested that query, it also brings back 12 records which is great but brings back nulls for years and now bring nulls back on totalreg!

Comment: Sorry, i forgot the COALESCE, modified my answer

Comment: It's still not correct, of course. A fiddle would have been nice.

Comment: HEHE yeh just noticed, but your query does exactly the same as mine, Still getting nulls in the years

Comment: "It's still not correct, of course. A fiddle would have been nice" what you mean?  As far as the problem is concerned, I already know that the query cant know if a null record should be a certain year.  so I'm asking, is there a way to achieve no nulls? or is this a nono cannot do?

Comment: The problem is not replacing the NULL with a value, that's COALESCE, it's how to decide which value, 2012 or 2013?

Comment: yes its replacing the null which is easy, but what to replace it with! scrol up theres an answer, have to set a range first

Comment: Modified my answer, now i assume a missing month will be from the current year if the month is less than the current month and from the previous year if it's greater or equal. You might change that logic to YEAR(DATEADD(MONTH, -mon+1,GETDATE()))

Comment: This is my last try :-)  Please check it out

Answer (score 0):

Here's my attempt at a solution:

```
declare @UserProfile table
(
    id bigint not null identity(1,1) primary key clustered
    , name nvarchar(32) not null
    , dateRegistered datetime not null default(getutcdate())
)
insert @UserProfile
select 'person 1', '2011-01-23'
union select 'person 2', '2013-01-01'
union select 'person 3', '2013-05-27'

declare @yearMin int, @yearMax int
select @yearMin = year(MIN(dateRegistered))
, @yearMax= year(MAX(dateRegistered))
from @UserProfile

;with monthCte as
(
    select 1 monthNo, DATENAME(month, '1900-01-01') Name
    union all
    select monthNo + 1, DATENAME(month, dateadd(month,monthNo,'1900-01-01'))
    from monthCte
    where monthNo < 12
)
, yearCte as
(
    select @yearMin yearNo
    union all
    select yearNo + 1
    from yearCte
    where yearNo < @yearMax
)
select y.yearNo, m.Name, COUNT(up.id) UsersRegisteredThisPeriod
from yearCte y
cross join monthCte m
left outer join @UserProfile up
    on year(up.dateRegistered) = y.yearNo
    and month(up.dateRegistered) = m.monthNo
group by y.yearNo, m.monthNo, m.Name
order by y.yearNo, m.monthNo
```

SQL Fiddle Version: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/6640